# Error using tcpdump in a command line list of commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to run tcpdump in the background while I send some traffic over eth0 and then pkill the tcpdump process after the traffic has been sent.

When I run tcpdump alone in the background it runs without error:

```
bash~~$ sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -i eth0 -s0 -w /tmp/eth0.pcap &
[1] 19282
bash~~$ tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes

bash~~$
```

Then I can pkill the tcpdump afterwards:

```
bash~~$ ps -ef | grep tcpdump; sleep 1; sudo pkill tcpdump; ps -ef | grep tcpdump
fred 20437 15842  0 11:55 pts/2    00:00:00 grep tcpdump
fred 20467 15842  0 11:55 pts/2    00:00:00 grep tcpdump
bash~~$
```

Now when I put the above all together I can't seem to get past the initial tcpdump call:

```
bash~~$ sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -i eth0 -s0 -w /tmp/eth0.pcap & ; ps -ef | grep tcpdump; sleep 1; sudo pkill tcpdump; ps -ef | grep     tcpdump;
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
bash~~$
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing? Does tcpdump behave different to other functions?

A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ampersand `&` is a pipeline terminator together with `;`, `&&` and `||`. You should not specify two different pipeline terminators together, but rather chose one depending on your needs. Here, you probably want

```
sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -i eth0 -s0 -w /tmp/eth0.pcap & ps -ef | grep tcpdump; sleep 1; sudo pkill tcpdump; ps -ef | grep tcpdump;
```

Relevant excerpts from the [bash manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of
>   the control operators `|` or `|&`.
>
> A list is a sequence of one or
>   more pipelines separated by one of the operators `;`, `&`, `&&`, or `││`, and
>   optionally terminated by one of `;`, `&`, or `<newline>`.